# Access Local variable in another method Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, google-api

I am looking to understand how I can access a variable set in method A, then use that variable in method B, and also a clean way of reusing the same part of code and then only changing the query

```
require 'google/api_client'

module GoogleAnalytics
 class Analytic

 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = ENV['SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS']
 PATH_TO_KEY_FILE              = ENV['PATH_TO_KEY_FILE']
 PROFILE                       = ENV['ANALYTICS_PROFILE_ID']

def google_analytics_api

client  = Google::APIClient.new(
  application_name: "Example Application",
  application_version: "1.0")

client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
  :issuer               => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
  :signing_key          => Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(PATH_TO_KEY_FILE, 'notasecret')).tap { |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }

  api_method = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3').data.ga.get


  # make queries
  result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
  'ids'        => PROFILE,
  'start-date' => Date.new(2014,1,1).to_s,
  'end-date'   => Date.today.to_s,
  'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
  'metrics'    => 'ga:pageviews',
  'filters'    => 'ga:pagePath==/'
 })
  end
 end
end
```

So if i run the method google_analytics_api i get a set of results returned assigned to the variable **result**.

So what if i want another 2 separate methods that will return different sets of results, so
new users and bounce rates, that would be two separate calls changing the request params wouldnt it? would i have to repeat the whole method?

Is there a way to refactor this so that the authorization call can be wrapped up in its on method and all i change is the request params assigned to result ?

So something like this

```
def api_call
  logic to make request
end

def new_users
  api_call
   # make queries
  result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
  'ids'        => PROFILE,
  'start-date' => Date.new(2014,1,1).to_s,
  'end-date'   => Date.today.to_s,
  'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
  'metrics'    => 'ga:newUsers',
  'filters'    => 'ga:pagePath==/'
 })


end
```

One of the problems though will be having the  local variables **client** and **result** available in the new_users method, what could these be changed to? an instance variable with an @? or a class variable with an @@ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your instincts are good - you [don't want to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and there are better ways of structuring this code. But rather than sharing *variables*, you should think about *small pieces, loosely joined*. Write methods that do one thing well, and combine them together. For instance, we could write a `get_client` method that just returns a `client` for other methods to use:

```
protected
def get_client
  client  = Google::APIClient.new(
    application_name: "Example Application",
    application_version: "1.0")

  client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    :issuer               => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    :signing_key          => Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(PATH_TO_KEY_FILE, 'notasecret')).tap { |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }
  client
end
```

It's `protected` because external code - stuff outside your `Analytic` class - shouldn't work with it directly. They should use the methods we provide for them.

---

You could also provide a helper method for getting results from the API. I'm not familiar with the query API, but it looks like it's your `metrics` value that changes. So maybe something like this:

```
protected
def get_result(metrics)
  client = self.get_client
  api_method = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3').data.ga.get

  result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
    'ids'        => PROFILE,
    'start-date' => Date.new(2014,1,1).to_s,
    'end-date'   => Date.today.to_s,
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
    'metrics'    => metrics,
    'filters'    => 'ga:pagePath==/'
   })
  result
end
```

---

Now you can write simple methods that your external classes can use:

```
def new_users
  get_result('ga:newUsers')
end

def total_visits
  get_result('ga:pageViews')
end
```

If you can, try to return simple data from these methods. Maybe `total_visits` is going to return `get_result('ga:pageViews')['totalsForAllResults']['ga:pageviews']` instead. Code outside your class shouldn't have to know about the GA data format to work with it. This is called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: thats a great answer, explained well, though one thing im unsure of is the call in get_result..... client = self.get_client...what is this doing? I have only ever used self in a model class

Comment: It's just invoking the `get_client` method, which returns a `client` for the method to use. You could write that line as `client = get_client` or `client = get_client()` too.

Comment: thank you very much, always great when you can learn a lot from an answer

Answer (score 2):

From talking on Skype, I think there are several things to look at

---

**Init**

Currently, you're using the `google_analytics_api` method every time you want to use the module. This is completely inefficient, and is partly why you have this issue now. Instead, I would create an `init` method, which will fire each time you [initialize the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125946/class-constructors-in-ruby) (and make `GoogleAnalytics` into a class of its own):

```
#lib/google_analytics.rb
Class GoogleAnalytics
   def initialize
       ... google_analytics_api method here
   end
end
```

This will allow you to treat your current module as a real Ruby object - like this:

```
@analytics = GoogleAnalytics.new #-> fires initialize method
```

This will give you the ability to call the object (which will pull the data from the API), and then split that data accordingly, for the different use cases you have.

---

**Instance Methods**

This leads me nicely onto the idea of *instance* methods

What you're referring to, and indeed what `Alex P` is referring to, is the idea of an *instance* method. This doubles as an *attribute* for an object, but essentially allows you to call a piece of functionality on an *instance* of a method.

So in Alex's example, you have:

```
def new_users
  get_result('ga:newUsers')
end
```

This is just calling an `instance` method of your class:

```
GoogleAnalytics::Analytic.new_users
```

This will create an instance of the `Analytic` class, and then call the `new_users` method (which should be a [`class method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)). This method will then allow you to call `instance` methods on the newly initialized object, hence the `get_result` method call

--

What I'm proposing is to use `instance methods` *after* the object has been initialized, giving you acesss to the data defined with `google_analytics_api`

For example:

```
#app/controllers/analyics_controller.rb
Class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @analytics = GoogleAnalytics.new
       @new_users = @analytics.new_users
   end
end

#lib/google_analytics.rb
Class GoogleAnalytics
   def initialize
       ... google_analytics_api method here
   end

   def new_users
      return [new_users_data]
   end
end
```

The one caveat to this is whether this will work without the module. I think it should, but it's untested for me